# Google script getBcc()

Tags: google-apps-script

getBcc() does not work correctly: 
 1. If we have only one email address result of getBcc() is empty; 
 2. If we have multiple emails result is not empty but without first email.

code: 
I'm getting a Message:
to: 1@g.com, 2@g.com
cc: 3@g.com, 4@g.com
bcc: 5@g.com, 6@g.com

google script:
var threads = GmailApp.search("in:inbox", 0, 10);
var to = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getTo();
var cc = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getCc();
var bcc = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getBcc();

// result:
to = '1@g.com, 2@g.com'
cc = '3@g.com, 4@g.com'
bcc = '6@g.com' // without 5@g.com !!!!

Comment: Post your code along with context.

Comment: I'm getting a Message:<br>
to: 1@g.com, 2@g.com<br>
cc: 3@g.com, 4@g.com<br>
bcc: 5@g.com, 6@g.com<br>

google script:
var threads = GmailApp.search("in:inbox", 0, 10);
var to = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getTo();
var cc = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getCc();
var bcc = threads[0].getMessages()[0].getBcc();

// result:
to = '1@g.com, 2@g.com'
cc = '3@g.com, 4@g.com'
bcc = '6@g.com' // without 5@g.com !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there only one email in the inbox? `Threads` returns an array and you're only checking the first email in the thread with `threads[0].getMessages[0]`. You need to iterate through each one with a loop.

Give this a try:

```
function search() {
  var messages = GmailApp.search("in: inbox", 0, 10);

  for(var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<messages[i].getMessages().length; j++) {
      var bcc = messages[i].getMessages()[j].getBcc();
      var to = messages[i].getMessages()[j].getTo();
      Logger.log("To: " + to + ", bcc: " + bcc);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "Is there only one email in the inbox?"
it doesn't matter
Your function is good, I think we have trouble with gmail settings
I sent from another address message with 3 Bcc addresses to the my gmail application and I receved only one Bcc address

Comment: You know, now that I think of it, I wonder if you only see _your_ BCC address (the one running the function). They're blind for a reason, so it wouldn't return an address you didn't own.